# How to read file from USB mass storage Device using Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, usb

I developed an MFC Dialog application in C++ in MS VS 2013 Ultimate under Windows 7 Maximal. As a progenitor of source code I use CodeProject paper in [Detecting Hardware Insertion or Removal](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal).

My application is a user-mode application. It is intended for detection of  adding or removing hardware from/to computer. For this purpose I handle `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message and call `RegisterDeviceNotification()` function in my application. So, schematically, my aplication does the following:

1. Calls `SetupDiGetClassDevs()` to get a handle of device info set `HDEVINFO`.
2. Calls `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()` to enumerate all the device in the info set. Upon each iteration, we will get a `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`.
3. During the enumeration, `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId()` is called to read the instance ID for each device. The instance ID is in the form of "USB\Vid_04e8&Pid_503b\0002F9A9828E0F06".
4. If the instance ID match the `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name`, then `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()` is called to retrieve the description or friendly name.

But now I'm in need of reading of file from USB mass storage device when this device is pluged in (when the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` device event has place). How can I do it programmatically in Visual C++?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL is a DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME which includes a mask of the drive letter assinged. So since you are only after mass storage devices the following works.

```
DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME *pj = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME*) lParam;
if (pj->dbcv_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYPE_VOLUME) {
    long um = pj->dbcv_unitmask;
    for ( int i=0; i < 26; i++ ) {
        if (um&1) break;
        um = um >> 1;
    }

    if ( i < 26 ) {
        char Drive  = 'A' + i;
    }
}
```

In practice, some drives are ready to read instantly, others need few seconds.